# InterfaceError (0, '') when using adbapi.ConnectionPool

Tags: python, mysql, database, connection-pooling, pymysql

I use database connection pool provided by `adbapi` of `twisted.enterprise` to realize the parallel database writes as follows

```
dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('pymysql', **config)

query = dbpool.runInteraction(insert, item)
query.addErrback(handler_error)

def insert(cursor, item):
    cursor.execute('SELECT id from area where name = %s', (item['area'],))
    area_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.execute('SELECT id from location where name = %s', (item['location'],))
    location_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO `community` (`community_id`,`name`, `area_id`, `location_id`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)'
    params = (item['community_id'], item['name'], area_id, location_id)
    cursor.execute(insert_sql, params)

def handler_error(self, failure):
    print('--------------database operation exception!!-----------------')
    print(failure)
```

I know that adbapi connectionPool offers one connection per method/thread, which means every `insert` has a db connection. However, there are three sql in the `insert` method, sharing the same connection and cursor.

I have searched google and found that `InterfaceError (0, '')` problem is probably because of the cursor being closed before the sql execution.

So in my circumstance, is that because I have three sql in the same method that causes the `InterfaceError (0, '')` exception. And any idea for dealing with it?

Comment: Interesting question